# Disabling form-submit w/ Enter-key in Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

On most of my webapps pages using the Master Page, the first button is a "close window"-button that will by default be executed when the enterkey is pressed. In these scenarios, I want nothing to happen instead.

I have made this work with a very ugly solution: I create an invisible button on the Masterpage and set it as the defaultbutton, and override the defaultbutton property on the pages where I actually want something to happen. There are 2 problems with this solution: 1) it is ugly, 2) a postback is made when the enterkey is pressed forcing the page to refresh, which could lead users to believe that they've achieved something by pressing the button.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Close-Button's [UseSubmitBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx)-Property to False.